# Pass function between two child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a component called Navigation.js in which I have three components, Movies, MyPage and Search. I only need to communicate between Search and Movies component here.

```
<Router>
 <nav>
   <li>
    <Link to='/'>Movies</Link>
    <Link to='/mypage'>My Page</Link>
   </li>
   <Search/> //Search Component
   
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/mypage">
         <MyPage />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/">
         <Movies/>
      </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

In Search Component I Have simple search form.

```
export const Search = (props) => {
     const searchTxt = useRef('');
     const submitSearchHandler = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault();
         const val = searchTxt.current.value;
      }
     return (
        <form onSubmit={submitSearchHandler}>
        <input ref={searchTxt} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
     )
}
```

In Movies component I have used Fetch to load movies from API. So What I am trying is whenever user clicks search inside search component I want execute fetchMovies Function inside Movies Component with search parameter from Search Component. Given Below

```
    const Movies = () => {
    const [movies, setmovies] = useState({data:[], loading:true})
    const fetchMovies = async (search='') => {
        setmovies({loading:true})
        const moviesResponse = await fetch('https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json? 
        query_term='+search);
        const data = await moviesResponse.json();
        const moviesdata = data.data;
        setmovies({data:moviesdata.movies,loading:false})
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMovies()
    },[])
    
    
   let content =  movies.data.map((movie) => {
            return <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>
             })
   return (
            <div>
               {content}
            </div>
       
       )
     }
```

Comment: If the Search component is only responsible for searching movies, it should be a child component of the Movies component.

Comment: Generally the solution here is to lift state up to a common ancestor. Pass an "onSubmit" callback to the search component, and pass the search results to the movie component. FullstackGuy is correct though, it seems the search component could easily be a child of the movies component. Side note: `setmovies({loading:true})` is going to delete the `data` state, so `movies.data.map` will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you've not used any state management libraries like Redux or MobX, the logical way of doing this would be to move the `searchTxt` and modify your previously defined `submitSearchHandler` handler function as a delegated event `onSearchText` (in your component this was doing the work of setting the value for search directly, now it'd delegate the work of setting the search text to some function one or more levels up in the component tree). This is known as "hoisting" in React and is often used for sharing variables and/or handler functions between more than one components in the tree.

This is how your `Search` component would look like:

```
export const Search = (props) => {
     const submitSearchHandler = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault();
         const val = searchTxt.current.value;
         props.onSearchText(val); // this is the event that will be handled
      }
     return (
        <form onSubmit={submitSearchHandler}>
        <input value={props.searchTxt} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
     )
}
```

Somewhere above your router jsx code in the same component, you'd handle setting the value for your `searchTxt` state variable, and pass down this value to the `Movies` component as a prop.

```
const [searchTxt, setSearchText] = useState('');

<Router>
 <nav>
   <li>
    <Link to='/'>Movies</Link>
    <Link to='/mypage'>My Page</Link>
   </li>
   <Search 
    searchTxt={searchTxt} 
    onSearchText={(text) => setSearchText(text)}
   />   
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/mypage">
         <MyPage />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/">
         <Movies searchTxt={searchTxt}/>
      </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

You'd declare a `useEffect` inside your `Movies` component with `searchTxt` as a dependency, thus triggering the `fetchMovies()` function everytime the search values changes.

```
    const Movies = ({searchTxt}) => {
    const [movies, setmovies] = useState({data:[], loading:true})
    
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
        setmovies({loading:true})
        const moviesResponse = await fetch('https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json? 
        query_term='+searchTxt);
        const data = await moviesResponse.json();
        const moviesdata = data.data;
        setmovies({data:moviesdata.movies,loading:false})
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if(searchText !== ""){
          fetchMovies()
        }
    },[searchTxt])
    
    
   let content =  movies.data.map((movie) => {
            return <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>
             })
   return (
            <div>
               {content}
            </div>
       
       )
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Lift shared state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the nearest common parent component in React.

Here as `<Search />` and `<Movies />` both need access to `searchTxt`. Keep it in the the `<Navigation />` component and pass it down to both concerned child components as props.

Also, replace the `useRef` with a `useState` hook in `<Navigation />` and pass `searchTxt and setSearchTxt` down as required.

Here is how `<Navigation />` will now look like:

```
const Navigation = () => {

const [searchTxt, setSearchTxt] = useState('');

return (
<Router>
 <nav>
   <li>
    <Link to='/'>Movies</Link>
    <Link to='/mypage'>My Page</Link>
   </li>
   <Search searchTxt={searchTxt} updateSearchText={setSearchTxt} />
   
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/mypage">
         <MyPage />
       </Route>
       <Route path="/">
         <Movies searchTxt={searchTxt} />
      </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router> 
)}
```

`<Search />` will look like this:

```
export const Search = ({searchTxt, updateSearchTxt}) => {
const [input, setInput] = useState(searchTxt);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateSearchTxt(input);
  }

     return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
     )
}
```

`<Movies />` would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want two components to communicate and you're not using a state management tool/context, you manage have a container that manages the state and API calls (known as ["lifting state up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) - and you have one - `<Navigation />`. `<Movies />` can then be a dumb component that *receives* and handles data rather than having to deal with its own API call.

Here's a working example using mock data, and a mock API call that returns JSON after two seconds.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const json = '["Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie4"]';

function mockApi() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 2000);
  });
}

function Navigation() {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  // A reference to handleSearch is passed into
  // the Search component so it can be called when
  // the button is clicked
  function handleSearch(value) {
    mockApi(value)
      .then(json => JSON.parse(json))
      .then(data => setMovies(data));
  }

  // Movies now simply receives the data that's
  // stored in state after the API call
  return (
    <div>
      <Search handleSearch={handleSearch} />
      <Movies movies={movies} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Search({ handleSearch }) {

  // Search has its own state
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  // Call the handleSearch function when the
  // button is clicked
  function handleClick() {
    handleSearch(input);
  }

  // Set the state
  function handleInput(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Movies is now just responsible for rendering the movie data
function Movies({ movies }) {
  return movies.map(movie => <div>{movie}</div>);
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Navigation />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```